# Should we avoid push segue loop between two view?

Tags: objective-c, loops, segue

Well, to some of you this question may sounds ridiculous but I'm discussing with my teammates about the design of an ios app and I need your opinion about it.

The old design which I disagree is as following

- We have ViewControllerA which contains Button "Go To B". The button has a PUSH segue to go to B.
- We have ViewControllerB which contains Button "Go To A".The button
  has a PUSH segue to go to A.
- We have to travel between the 2 ViewController a lot.

As you can see, there is a segue loop between ViewController A and B and I think we should never let it happens. I would prefer go from B to A by "Back" button in navigation bar.

How serious is the PUSH segue loop in design? Is it acceptable in some cases? Where can I see the recommended good design by apple (if there are any?)

**EDIT:** I try "pop before push" solution by nfarshchi but it do not work.This is how I did:
1) I cannot create segue from VC A to VC B and segue from VC B to VC A at the same time. It seems that storyboard prevents it from happening
2) Thus I create one segue whose identifier is "gotoB" from Button "Go to B" in VC A to VC B and one segue whose identifier is "gotoA" from Button "Go to A" in VC B to VC A.

So the Storyboard would looks like this:

VC X ---Push---> VC A <----Push----> VC B
(The reason I need ViewController X is explained later)
3) In VC A I have this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Prepage for segue go to B") ;
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"gotoB"] ) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    }
}
```

I need VC X because I cannot pop a ViewController from Stack if there is only one ViewController in there.

Now it seems right, but when I clicked "Go to B", it went to VC X instead. It was clearly that the above popViewControllerAnimated: has poped VC A, and that's all, the segue to VC B was no longer fired. The result was the VC B was not pushed into Stack as expected.

Thus I think it is unfeasible to implement nfarshchi's solution

Answer (score 3):

You can do that but consider when you push out a `UIViewController` and again push it in you will call a lot of methods to re design it. if you want to move over them a lot it is better to use `UINavigationController`. in this case you only make them once and you can navigate between them easily.
this will use less system resources

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think your solution about "pop before push" will work

Comment: No man, I did not mean you pop before you push, I was telling by using `UINavigationController` you only push your `UIViewController` once and also you can have a simple back button. and there is no need of pop it again. `UINavigationController` will do that for you.

Comment: Consider you have `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`. on `A` you can have a Button and [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];

Comment: `UINavigationController` will add a `Back` Button to `NavigationBar` that will show you `A` again. and again by pressing your Button you will go to `B` , you do not make it again you just show it again. if you mention even the `ViewDidLoad` method will not call twice

Comment: Thanks, I get it. So your solution is the same as me, we use "Back" button in NavigationBar instead of creating new Button with PUSH segue to B.

Answer (score 1):

The push/pop transition should only be used if the virtual 2D space that the transition creates is realistic. If the user sees 10 push transitions in a row, it is going to feel like they are going deeper and deeper into a hierarchy and it can lead confusion and a bad mental model, especially if in reality you are just moving between two view controllers.

Using the back button would be a better solution, or you can make your own custom transition which makes it clearer to the user what is going on. Perhaps a flipside transition would also be appropriate.